# What does this guy say in the video?

Tags: listening

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bs_Ej32IYgo&app=desktop

Hi, I'm trying to teach myself by watching Youtube videos, but sometimes I do have problems understand exactly what they're saying in their videos, and this is one of them. So, please let me know what this guy saying at 11:33 to 11:35 if you guys don't mind. 
I guess he's saying, You'll notice this keeps my chine almost perfect.... something. Thank you.

Comment: "You'll notice this keeps my shins almost perpendicular with the ground below me." That part? He does mumble a bit there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"keeps my shins"**

also known as "the tibial region"

> - [**shin**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shin) -  "The front part of the leg below the knee and above the ankle."